# How to write lengthy numbers in csv without getting converted into scientific notation

Tags: java, csv, number-formatting, apache-commons

I'm writing lengthy numbers as a string into a csv file. Problem is, these are notified in scientific notation.

```
2019100000000000 as 2.02E+15
```

is there a way to avoid this in Java? I'm using apache commons library to create the csv.

```
private String visitNumber;
public String getVisitNumber() {
    return visitNumber;
}

List<CsvRecord> records = loadData();
    for (PrivateCorporatePatientListingCsv record : records) {
        csvPrinter.printRecord(
                record.getVisitNumber()
        );
    }
```

Comment: How did you find out they are denoted in scientific notation? I hope you didn't open the csv file with Excel... Can you show us how you are writing the numbers?

Comment: You could write the numbers as strngs, as long as strings without separator characters are exported without quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `BigInteger` (integral values) or `BigDecimal` (fixed point) as value holding class, and not floating point, that also only approximates the value (1.2 == 1.2000 == actually 1.199999999978 or such).

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("2019100000000000");
String s = x.toPlainString(); // 2019100000000000
```

Comment: But still visitNumber is a String value. So do i need to convert it into a BigDecimal and again to a String?

Comment: I probably do not understand what exactly is happening. The code already receives a string with scientific E-notation to write to CSV? Then the caller of visitNumber is doing its own wrong number-to-string conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify how you want number to get converted to String using NumberFormat, and in this case, a subclass, [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)